# Print Preview issue using wkWebView iOS 10

Tags: ios, printing, webkit, wkwebview

I have to print big document of 55 pages that contains english as well as arabic text. I am using `WKWebView.viewPrintFormattor`. In iOS 9 the document is printed properly, but in iOS 10 I am getting a blank page on the print preview.

[image]

Comment: Did my solution work ?

Comment: @Randy i am using same code, that i snot working for ios 10 but will work for ios 9. i have an html that contains table tag, inside of table tag there is arabic and english text.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the document you want to print ?

Comment: @Randy document is private. sorry i cannot share.

Comment: All right got it. Then you could check if it works with lighter documents ( like 1 page, 2 pages, 10 pages etc... ). It might also be a bug in iOS 10 itself.

Comment: there is no page limit for simple text, i tried. but i think this issue is coming due to arabic text with tables. Please suggest any library or solution.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
func presentPrintControllerForWebView(_ webView: WKWebView)
{
        guard let urlCheck = webView.url
            else {return}

        let pi = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
        pi.outputType = .general
        pi.jobName = urlCheck.absoluteString
        pi.orientation = .portrait
        pi.duplex = .longEdge

        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        printController.printInfo = pi
        printController.showsPageRange = true
        printController.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()
        printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: on some pages which contains model it is showing blank page